# Can't deploy shiny in 3 files because server is not found

Tags: r, shiny

I have an app that is working, but i have tried to split my application into 3 files: ui.R, server.R and start.R, so I can deploy it on shinyapps.io and it's getting this error:

Error in shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server) : object 'server' not found

The start.R file consists of loading the packages I need, and this command:

```
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Can you please help me solve this?

Answer (score 1):

If you use two files you should not use `shinyApp` but instead call `runApp("dir")`, where "dir" is the directory `ui.R` and `server.R` are located.

Answer (score 0):

Did you define your server in server.R?

```
# Define server function
server <- function(input, output) {
  # Server logic goes here
}
```

Make sure your server.R is in the same directory as the ui.R and start.R

Comment: yes, it's defined like this:

    library(shiny)
    server <- function(input, output, session) {
    }

Also it is in the same directory.